# How to fill in ComboBox from an API call?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I need to call an API, get a response, add items to ComboBox and update the view in the plugin.

[Attached is the image of the combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqW7h.png)

I need to update the thread Ids as they load from an API. My custom Combobox for this is as shown below. I am not sure how to update the custom component from outside the class. Any help?

```
public class MyComboBox extends AnAction implements CustomComponentAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(@NotNull AnActionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull JComponent createCustomComponent(@NotNull Presentation presentation, @NotNull String place) {

        ComboBox<String> jComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        jComboBox.setMinLength(100);
        jComboBox.addItem("Thread Id: " + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        jComboBox.addItem("Thread Id: " + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        jComboBox.setEnabled(true);

        return jComboBox;

    }

}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) - you should learn that all Swing components come with a "model", which can be independent on the component, so you should be updating the model.  Also, Swing is not thread safe, so beware of that as well

Comment: I understand the model part, my createCustomComponents gets called before I can set jComboBox.setModel(model), how do I update the jComboBox from an outside class?

Comment: The [JComboBox API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) has all kinds of useful methods, including `getModel` and `setModel`, just to name two.

Comment: I needed a reference of the already instantiated combobox, the below code helped me.
MyComboBox myComboBox = (MyComboBox) ActionManager.getInstance().getAction("searchThread");
        myComboBox.updateUI(newList);

Comment: Another method exposed in MyComboBox called updateUI:

public void updateUI(List<String> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
        String[] array = this.ids.toArray(new String[0]);

        jComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(array));

        jComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

        jComboBox.updateUI();
    }

Answer (score 0):

I needed a reference to the already instantiated combobox.
I got it with

```
MyComboBox myComboBox = (MyComboBox) ActionManager.getInstance().getAction("searchThread")
```

I added another method in MyComboBox:

```
public void updateUI(List<String> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
        String[] array = this.ids.toArray(new String[0]);

        jComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(array));

        jComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

        jComboBox.updateUI();
    }
```

and used:

```
myComboBox.updateUI(newList);
```

That solved my problem.